# How to remove website field in comment form?

Tags: comments, comment-form

I am using `<?php comments_template(); ?>` to show my comment form and I'm trying to remove the url field so I added this to my functions

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'clear_url_box');
function clear_url_box($fields){
    if(isset($fields['url']))
    unset($fields['url']);
    return $fields;
}
```

this is my single.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content">
<div id="singleimg">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                    <?php the_content('Read more on "'.the_title('', '', false).'" &raquo;'); ?>

                    <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>Pages:</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>
                    <div id="tags"><?php the_tags( '<p>Tags: ', ', ', '</p>'); ?></div>


</div>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

                <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php comments_template(); ?>

</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

but it's not working. Anyone know how to fix this? my site is `http://toarumajutsunoindex.me/test/`

Comment: It worked for me.

Comment: it doesn't work for me :( I added my site for you to see live

Comment: Make sure you are putting it in right theme. Confirm it by placing an exit; call. Plus, adds a third priority parameter and set it to 99 (just in case).

Comment: Can you show us your `comments.php` template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme should have a comments.php file.  Can you just remove the field there?  For instance, my comments.php files has the following code:

```
    <p class="field"><label for="url"><?php _e('Website', 'theme1721'); ?> </label><input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo esc_attr($comment_author_url); ?>" size="22" tabindex="3" /></p>
```

I would just remove it if I didn't want visitors to have the option to leave a url.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your answer isn't always correct. WordPress themes should use `comment_form` function, so there is a chance, that you won't find this field.

Answer (score -1):

**The Easy Way**

The least destructive way is also the easiest, using CSS:

```
#commentform > p.comment-form-url {display:none;}
```

**The Hard Way**

Open `\wp-includes\comment-template.php` and remove or comment out the following lines:

```
    'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website' ) . '</label> ' .
                '<input id="url" name="url" ' . ( $html5 ? 'type="url"' : 'type="text"' ) . ' value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" maxlength="200" /></p>',
```

Comment: Do not edit core files; they will be overwritten after the next update. Use the existing filters instead.